# Django 'resolve' : get the url name instead of the view_function

Tags: python, django, django-urls

My problem is simple, I have an url, I would like to resolve it, but get the `url` name instead of the view function associated with it ...

For example... this is urlconf :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
    url('^/books/$', book_list, name="overview_books"),
...
)
```

And this is what I would like :

```
>>> resolve('/books/')
'overview_books'
```

Do you know any way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this snippet (originally taken from <s>djangosnippets.org/snippets/1378/</s>);

```
>>> from my_projects.tools import resolve_to_name
>>> print resolve_to_name('/some/url')
'app.views.view'
>>> print resolve_to_name('/some/other/url')
'this_is_a_named_view'
```

;)

Answer (score 33):

In Django 1.3 and newer you can use [resolve](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) function:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
print resolve('/books/').url_name
```

Comment: Also useful in the case you have:
`resolver = resolve('/books/39/')` then
`requested_book_id = resolver.args[0]`

Comment: in newer versions of django its from django.urls import resolve